# Multiple redux reducers from same reducer module

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, reducers, cloning

Hi everyone,

I'm developing an application in react/redux and I'm trying to dynamically inject different copies of the same reducer into the store. I've been successful at dynamically injecting reducers into the store, but it seems the reducers end up all being linked to the same reducer (i.e. issuing actions to one reducer affects all the injected reducers). I've tried many different ways of reassigning the reducer function, but they all don't work:

```
Function.prototype.clone = function () {
  var newFunc;
eval('newFunc=' + this.toString());
for (var key in this) {
  newFunc[key] = initialState[key];
}
  return newFunc;
}
```

And lodash clone, defining the function when I inject the reducer, defining the function and then calling new [function]. None of them work. When the new reducer is injected, it immediately copies the state from other reducers and actions affect all the reducers.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do with `clone`. if you want to reuse much of the same reducer logic then make a function that returns a reducer. then you can call that function as much as you want and get a unique reducer every time. of course if you want to handle actions separately you'll need to namespace actions or something but that's easily done with a normal function

Comment: That doesn't work. I made a function that defines and returns the reducer, and it still mirrors the other reducers. I'm checking to make sure the reducer only returns an altered state if the key I've stored in the action matches a global key, but the change in one is still mirrored across all instances.

Comment: it definitely does work, here's a simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ybryic

Comment: I can write that up as a solution. not sure if this still has some limitations for you

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. I think the problem was that I was naming the function: (i.e. const reducer = (...) => {...}; return reducer;) instead of just returning an unnamed function. Thank you all so much.